# How to prove that $x\notin {\{a,b,c}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let there be a set $\{a,b,c\}$.

I want to prove that for an element $x$, such that $x \ne a, x \ne b, x \ne c$, it's true that $x\notin {\{a,b,c}\}$. Assuming only ZFC axioms, the law of non-contradiction and the law of excluded middle, how to do it?

Comment: If $x$ is a set, $\{x\}$ is a different set by wellfoundedness.

Comment: What's the formal proof of that? I don't know which axioms are you basing the above statement on.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: While true, I don't see how that is connected with the question.

Comment: Really, @dsddsadasdasdasdsadasdgfdf? 15 questions so far and no accepted answer? You seem to have very high standards, then!

Comment: How do you define $\{a,b,c\}$ in the first place?

Comment: @AlexM. $\{a\}$, $\{\{a\}\}$ etc. give us infinitely many (we need only 4) elements, not all of which can be $b$ or $c$...

Comment: Even if this question does not provide information or context, it rises an important question in set theory , because the question asks how can we deduce  a conclusion  using only the axioms.

Answer (score 4):

As the notation is not part of the original language of ZFC, we have to *define* first what the notation $\{a,b,c\}$ even *means*.

One of the axioms of ZFC is

**Axiom of Pairing.** If $a,b$ are sets then there exists a set $c$ with
 $$\forall x(x\in c\leftrightarrow (x=a\lor x=b)) $$

Per the Axiom of Extensionality, this set is in fact unique. This allows us to *define* (i.e., make a conservative extension of our language and theory)

**Definition 1.** If $a,b$ are sets, we write $\{a,b\}$ for the unique set $c$ guaranteed to exist by the Axiom of Pairing applied to $a,b$.

For convenience, we also make

**Definition 2.** If $a$ is a set we write  $\{a\}$ as a shorthand for $\{a,a\}$.

We also have the

**Axiom of Union.** If $a$ is a set then there exists a set $b$ such that
$$\forall x(x\in b\leftrightarrow\exists y(x\in y\land y\in a)) $$

Per the Axiom of Extensionality, this set is once again unique. This allows us to make the

**Definition 3.** If $a$ is a set, we write $\bigcup a$ for the unique set $b$ guaranteed to exist by the Axiom of Union applied to $a$.

**Definition 4.** Let $a,b$ be sets. Then we write $a\cup b$ as a shorthand for $\bigcup \{a,b\}$.

Now we have enough notation at hand to make the

**Definition 5.** Let $a,b,c$ be sets. Then we write $\{a,b,c\}$ as a shorthand for $\{a,b\}\cup\{c\}$.

Now we can prove

**Theorema Egregium Theoriae Conjunctorum** If $a,b,c,x$ are sets then
$$x\in \{a,b,c\}\iff (x=a\lor x=b\lor x=c) $$

*Proof.* Expand all definitions and simplify. $\square$

**Corollary.** If $x\ne a$, $x\ne b$, and $x\ne c$, then $x\notin\{a,b,c\}$.

*Proof.* Elementary. $\square$